# How can I add a second fan to this circuit? Directly control the fans?

Tags: fan

I want to add a a second fan to my laptop.
On its mainboard there is just one fan connector but there are also 3 exposed contact points nearby. Could I somehow use them for that?

JFAN1 is the exposed Fan Connector.
The contact points are labeled "D15" which on the scheme is in the right middle. I do not quite understand that particular section of the scheme.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: In that schematic, D15 is a diode, not a connector.

Comment: Yes there is a diode and caps there. But it seems that either before or after them, each of the 3 D15 lines get exposed as a blob on the surface. Around these 3 there is a label "D15.  But as I understand it better and seeing the space constraints on the real board...

Comment: But then I dont get the reason for exposing the D15 lines that prominent if one cant use it because the other lines are deeper.

Comment: I bet it would be easier to just splice the fan connector -.-

Answer (score 1):

D15 has only 2 pin. Where is the Third one? looking to schematics it is cleary that if you connect your new fan to point labelled D15 (leave third one floating), you'll have a fan to a fixed speed. you must undersand were third pin is connected, if it is connect to JFAN1's  second pin, it will work. try with a tester, 2 connector must be in parallel.

Comment: PLease explain that further! I might have totally misunderstood all this but do you think its actually possible? Yes D15 has 3 pin.

Comment: D15 is a SOT23-3 package that has 3 pins. 2 of the 3 pins are either connected together inside the package or 1 pin is unused and not connected to anything inside the chip package.

Comment: I think that what you see as D15 is a not mounted diode and not a not mounted fan connector. so, it will be easier for you to split signal directly on cable. how do you think to solder new fan on d15 pin? u35 is a voltage regulator. i think it will not have problem to drive two fan at time. (in teory it is designed just for one fan at time)